# Does react recreate the callback wrapped with useCallback in each rerender?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I use `useCallback` hook like this:

```js
const App = () => {
   const [name,setName] = useState('')
   const [count,setCount] = useState(0)
   const fn = useCallback(() => {
      console.log("I'm a callback")
   },[name])
   return <div onClick = {() => setCount(count => count + 1)}>{count}</div>
}
```

When `count` changes, the component will rerender. Is the callback function wrapped with `useCallback` recreated? Which one below is the true condition?

1. Never recreate the callback when the rerender is caused by `count` changes. `fn` is always the initial callback itself.
2. The callback will be recreated as long as there is a rerender happens. Rerender means calling the `App` function again, which means executed the codes again. So each rerender has a new callback function. But since the dep `name` doesn't change, the `useCallback` hook will still return the previous callback.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback):

> Returns a memoized callback.

So, that means #2 is true, since memoization doesn't mean "never call the function" (which is your #1 condition). Instead, memoization means "when the function is called, return the same value for the same inputs" so `useCallback` is called, but the previously stored value (`fn`) is returned.

Here's an example of a memoized `add` function.

```js
function memoizedAdd(a, b) {
  memoizedAdd.cache = memoizedAdd.cache ?? {};
  
  if (typeof memoizedAdd.cache[`${a,b}`] === 'undefined') {
    console.log('returning "new" value')
    memoizedAdd.cache[`${a,b}`] = a + b;
  }

  
  return memoizedAdd.cache[`${a,b}`]
}



console.log(memoizedAdd(1,2))
console.log(memoizedAdd(1,2))
console.log(memoizedAdd(1,2))
console.log(memoizedAdd(1,2))
```

Comment: The condition one didn't say "never call the function". What it said is calling the `useCallback` again without decalring the callback wrapped in the hook again, and returned previously stored value. The doubt point here is whether the callback will be declared again. Condition one said it won't.

Comment: Ah, well, it's important to know that the value passed into `useCallback` is a value. This means that it has been declared regardless of `useCallback`'s behavior. Memory is being consumed simply because the function exists in the browser.